# module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'distplot'

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, data-science

I've some code like:

```
   import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv('StudentsPerformance.csv')

#print(data.isnull().sum()) // checking if there are some missing values or not
#print(data.dtypes)checking datatypes of the dataset

# ANALYSİS VALUES OF THE COLUMN'S
"""print(data['gender'].value_counts())
print(data['parental level of education'].value_counts())
print(data['race/ethnicity'].value_counts()) 
print(data['lunch'].value_counts())
print(data['test preparation course'].value_counts())"""

# Adding column total and average to the dataset
data['total'] = data['math score'] + data['reading score'] + data['writing score']
data['average'] = data ['total'] / 3

sns.distplot(data['average'])
```

I would like to see distplot of average for visualization but I run the program that gives me an error like

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/usersample/PycharmProjects/untitled1/sample.py", line 22, in
>   
>       sns.distplot(data['average']) AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'distplot'

I've tried to reinstall and install seaborn and upgrade the seaborn to 0.9.0 but it doesn't work.

> head of my data female,"group B","bachelor's
>   degree","standard","none","72","72","74" female,"group C","some
>   college","standard","completed","69","90","88" female,"group
>   B","master's degree","standard","none","90","95","93" male,"group
>   A","associate's degree","free/reduced","none","47","57","44"

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: "but it doesn't work" is never a useful problem description. Did you successfully install seaborn 0.9 and reran the script to find out that the same error is produced, or was installation of seaborn 0.9 not successful?

Comment: I tried running your code and it worked perfectly fine for me and my seaborn version is 0.9.0

Comment: I've successfully installed seaborn 0.9  there no problem with that but I still get the same error. I cannot use distplot, pairplot etc. functions.

Comment: I've deleted python and pycharm and reinstalled then the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

this might be due to removal of paths in environment variables section. Try considering to add your IDE scripts and python folder. I am using pycharm IDE, and did the same and its working fine.